How can I set the character-set from the command line?
How can I change the Visual Studio project setting "Character Set" to "Not set" from the command line? By default it is setting this option to "Unicode Character Set", and I need to be able to change this without using the below dialog.


This is not C++ specific - and have you tried looking at the VS documentation?

Unicode Character Set is compile option:  /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE"
If you don't add unicode, it will be Not set.
/D "_MBCS"  is  MBCS

For cl.exe, do not add /D "UNICODE" macros. For building vcxproj, set the character msbuild projectname.vcxproj /p:CharacterSet=NotSet.
